# MySQL Select statement trouble

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Look at the pic. How it even possible? How to avoid this?

I've no records with `StartDate>='2013123-12-1'`
[image]

Comment: How to avoid that? Use proper date formats

Comment: MySQL is fixing the date for you, and since it is invalid, it probably, but I am not 100% certain, converting it to NULL, so it is now doing StartDate >= NULL. Anyway, do you see it says `1 warning`, do `show warnings` after your query, you will see what it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum year supported by MySQL is 9999.

> MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/datetime.html :